# Unexpected outcome of the "before insert" triger with subquery and EXISTS predicate along with further PK violation

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird, composite-primary-key, firebird2.5

I am managing a legacy web-app which process data using Firebird 2.5-based DB (runs on Ubuntu 18.04 server). All was OK for years, but I got something very strange recently.

There is a table with combined keys:

```sql
/******************************************************************************/
/*                                   Tables                                   */
/******************************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE STAT_VALIDATION (
    DATAREPORTID  D$BIGINT NOT NULL /* D$BIGINT = BIGINT */,
    PARAMGROUPID  D$INTEGER NOT NULL /* D$INTEGER = INTEGER */,
    KINDID        D$BIGINT NOT NULL /* D$BIGINT = BIGINT */,
    VALIDATIONID  D$BIGINT NOT NULL /* D$BIGINT = BIGINT */,
    ARG1          U$VARCHAR500 NOT NULL /* U$VARCHAR500 = VARCHAR(500) */,
    ARG2          U$VARCHAR500 /* U$VARCHAR500 = VARCHAR(500) */,
    NOTE          U$TEXTBLOB NOT NULL /* U$TEXTBLOB = BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80 */
);
/******************************************************************************/
/*                                Primary keys                                */
/******************************************************************************/
ALTER TABLE STAT_VALIDATION ADD CONSTRAINT PK_STAT_VALIDATION PRIMARY KEY (DATAREPORTID, PARAMGROUPID, KINDID, VALIDATIONID);
/******************************************************************************/
/*                                Foreign keys                                */
/******************************************************************************/
ALTER TABLE STAT_VALIDATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STAT_VALIDATION_DATAREPORTID FOREIGN KEY (DATAREPORTID, PARAMGROUPID, KINDID) REFERENCES STAT_DATA (DATAREPORTID, PARAMGROUPID, KINDID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE STAT_VALIDATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STAT_VALIDATION_VALIDATIONID FOREIGN KEY (VALIDATIONID) REFERENCES CONTENTTREE (NODEID) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

It also has a "before insert" trigger

```sql
/* Trigger: STAT_VALIDATION_BI0 */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER STAT_VALIDATION_BI0 FOR STAT_VALIDATION
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
as
declare variable PARAMS D$VARCHAR500;
begin
  if (exists (
    select *
    from STAT_VALIDATION SV
    where SV.DATAREPORTID = new.DATAREPORTID
    and SV.PARAMGROUPID = new.PARAMGROUPID
    and SV.KINDID = new.KINDID
    and SV.VALIDATIONID = new.VALIDATIONID
  )) then
  begin
    select list(VSPG.PARAMNAME || '=' || VSPG.PARAMVALUE, ';')
    from V_STAT_PARAMGROUPS VSPG
    where VSPG.PARAMGROUPID = new.PARAMGROUPID
    into :PARAMS;

    exception E_CUSTOM_EXCEPTION 'Validation already exists: '
      || 'DATAREPORTID=' || new.DATAREPORTID
      || '; PARAMGROUPID=' || new.PARAMGROUPID
      || '; KINDID=' || new.KINDID
      || '; VALIDATIONID=' || new.VALIDATIONID
      || '; PARAMS: ' || :PARAMS;
  end
end
```

Data in the table looks like this
[Table data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8rMt.png), so values in each of `DATAREPORTID`, `PARAMGROUPID`, `KINDID`, `VALIDATIONID` repeats - and only their combination must be unique.

**The problem**

A NEW record going to be inserted with the following values
`DATAREPORTID=214746; PARAMGROUPID=45542; KINDID=48062; VALIDATIONID=99517`
(ARGs also exist but those content are insignificant there)
And I got the following error message

> Firebird statement execute error : exception 1 E_CUSTOM_EXCEPTION
> Validation already exists: DATAREPORTID=214746; PARAMGROUPID=45542;
> KINDID=48062; VALIDATIONID=99517; PARAMS:
> STAT_PARAM_SPECIALITYID=454;STAT_PARAM_EDUFORMID=444;STAT_P
> ARAM_EDUBASISID=449;STAT_PARAM_COUNTRYID=545;STAT_PARAM_COURSE=740 At
> trigger 'STAT_VALIDATION_BI0' line: 19, col: 5

**An attempt of investigation**

For investigation, I have executed a select part of the query from trigger manually (using IB Expert remotely):

```sql
select *
    from STAT_VALIDATION SV
    where SV.DATAREPORTID = 214746
    and SV.PARAMGROUPID = 45542
    and SV.KINDID = 48062
    and SV.VALIDATIONID = 99517
```

As I expect, no records found:

[image: Query results]

Same way I have checked for only DATAREPORTID value:

```sql
select *
    from STAT_VALIDATION SV
    where SV.DATAREPORTID = 214746
```

Also - no records found (which is correct)

Some additional info:
When I remove condition and run test query again:

```sql
select *
    from STAT_VALIDATION SV
    where SV.PARAMGROUPID = 45542
    and SV.KINDID = 48062
    and SV.VALIDATIONID = 99517
```

- I am receiving existing record:
  [image: existing record (previous)]
- which is expected by logic of this app.
  But in this record value of DATAREPORTID is different.

Almost in desperation I have deactivated trigger and tried to insert mentioned record again
This time I got the following error

> Firebird statement execute error : violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY
> constraint "PK_STAT_VALIDATION" on table "STAT_VALIDATION" Problematic
> key value is ("DATAREPORTID" = 214746, "PARAMGROUPID" = 45542,
> "KINDID" = 48062, "VALIDATIONID" = 99517)

Could somebody at least explain for:
Why trigger has been fired?
Why PK violation has happens?
We have a composite PK based on 4 fields
DATAREPORTID, PARAMGROUPID, KINDID, VALIDATIONID
Within given new record:

- value of DATAREPORTID not available in this DB table,
- values of PARAMGROUPID, KINDID, VALIDATIONID - have been repeated in this DB table.
  As for me final combination must be unique and PK requiremets have to be fulfilled. But trigger has been fired / PC violation ossurs.
  How it is possible?
  Or do I miss (do not know) something important?

As I noted in post - I have tried to execute sub-query manually and got expected responses. But of the trigger and PK constraints is incorrect.

Comment: Do you get a result when you query with `SV.DATAREPORTID+0 = 214746` instead of `SV.DATAREPORTID = 214746`? If so, you have a corrupt index. Use `ALTER INDEX <indexname> ACTIVE` to rebuild it (any index containing `DATAREPORTID`).

Comment: It looks like client code performs INSERT (or whatever invoking INSERT) twice. Because of this you get the exception or PK violation for second insert attempt. After that whole transaction is rolled back and naturally your selects see nothing. Trace and Audit service can help investigate this case.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for suggestion . Query with SV.DATAREPORTID+0 = 214746 also returns 0 records if being executed manually. Anyway I have tried to alter all indexes ot this table as you suggest. Unfortunately with the same result - all query runs OK but when I submits data via UI - "before insert" being triggered with same message

Comment: @user13964273
App is live, data being submitted via UI without any prob;em - excep this one for this specific case.

Comment: Even live apps can have very live bugs. Trace and Audit **is** useful.

Comment: @user13964273 I agree. This might be one. But most of "business logick" of this app has been implementsd as DB objects - stored procedures, trigers, etc... 
Thank you for advise about Trace and Audit. Sorry, could you recommend some manual / guide om it - I have never used it and there is no much info on their website?

Comment: Really? https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rnfb25-trace.html

Comment: Thanks for all who provided your suggestons.
After dozens of hours of debugging I figured out that error was caused by inconsitency within input data package, provided by custimer - which had edited XML (input source for this app) manually.

Hovewer, case itself remains actual in my opinion. Because, combination of data values had been supplied for the BI triger / PK constraint was definitely uniqe. Thus - errors had been raised. At least - I still have not understand reasons for error(s)